AKS - Running containers as root user should be avoided
I could see the following Recommendations in Microsoft Defender for Cloud

Affected Resources:

however, I have set the following configuration in Keycloak
settings = {
  // ... other settings ...
  "containerSecurityContext.enabled"                 = "true"
  "containerSecurityContext.runAsUser"               = "1001"
  "containerSecurityContext.runAsNonRoot"            = "true"
  "containerSecurityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation"= "false"
  // ... other settings ...
}

Why does it still think that keycloak Pod is running as a root user? How do I fix this?
Update - May 6th 2024:
% kubectl get pod keycloak-0 -n keycloak -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].securityContext}'
{"allowPrivilegeEscalation":false,"capabilities":{"drop":["ALL"]},"privileged":false,"readOnlyRootFilesystem":false,"runAsGroup":1001,"runAsNonRoot":true,"runAsUser":1001,"seccompProfile":{"type":"RuntimeDefault"}}%                                                                                                                           

% kubectl get pod keycloak-0 -n keycloak -o jsonpath='{.spec.securityContext}'
{"fsGroup":1001,"fsGroupChangePolicy":"Always"}%                                                                                                                         

% kubectl exec -it keycloak-0 -n keycloak -- sh
Defaulted container "keycloak" out of: keycloak, init-quarkus-directory (init)
$ id
uid=1001(keycloak) gid=1001 groups=1001


can you verify and share the actual running configuration of your Keycloak pod by using the following - kubectl get pod [pod-name] -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].securityContext}' If you see all good from pod side then Microsoft Defender for Cloud might be showing outdated information due to caching or delayed scans.   If there are conflicting security context settings at the pod level that override the container-level settings, this could also be an issue. Check the pod-level security contexts- kubectl get pod [pod-name] -o jsonpath='{.spec.securityContext}'

I have a feeling that your Keycloak pod is configured to run with a non-root user ID (1001), but the group ID (gid) remains at 0 (root). example
This might cause some security tools or policies to still flag the container because the group is root, even though the user is not. Run the below command to check the status-
`kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=keycloak -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -- /bin/bash`


If you see something like this then to address this and ensure both the user and group IDs are set to non-root values, you need to adjust your Kubernetes deployment configuration like this- securityContext:         runAsUser: 1001         runAsGroup: 1001  # Set GID to a non-root value         runAsNonRoot: true         allowPrivilegeEscalation: false once done won't see any defender alert-

Thank you, @Arko. I have set the runAsGroup as you suggested. I will wait for the defender to refresh.

The issue you're encountering with Microsoft Defender for Cloud still flagging your Keycloak pod as running as a root user, despite having configured it to run as a non-root user, can be caused by several factors
Double-check that the security context settings are properly applied and reflected at both the pod and container levels
kubectl get pod -l app=keycloak -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.securityContext} {.items[*].spec.containers[*].securityContext}'

This command will show the security context settings for both the pod and its containers. Confirm that runAsUser, runAsNonRoot, and allowPrivilegeEscalation settings are correctly reflected.

Check if there are any cluster-wide policies or specific configurations in your AKS setup that might override the security context specified in your deployment. Review any Pod Security Policies (PSP) or other admission controllers that might be enforcing different rules. Check for any Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) settings or security policies that might influence pod execution behaviors.
Sometimes, the security recommendations may not update immediately after changes. Force an update or re-scan in Microsoft Defender for Cloud, if possible, to ensure it reflects the current state of your cluster.
I have a feeling that your Keycloak pod is configured to run with a non-root user ID (1001), but the group ID (gid) remains at 0 (root). This might cause some security tools or policies to still flag the container because the group is root, even though the user is not. Run the below command to check the status-
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=keycloak -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") -- /bin/bash


If you see something like this then to address this and ensure both the user and group IDs are set to non-root values, you need to adjust your Kubernetes deployment configuration. Here’s how you can modify it to include the runAsGroup directive, which wasn't previously set based on your output.
Update your deployment YAML to explicitly set both runAsUser and runAsGroup to non-root values.
Example
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1001
        runAsGroup: 1001  # Set GID to a non-root value
        runAsNonRoot: true
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1001
          runAsGroup: 1001  # Ensure the container also enforces this GID
          runAsNonRoot: true
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false

you can apply the same using- kubectl apply -f keycloak-deployment.yaml and verify.



Did not get any running container as root related notification.
